# Create new rows and repeat the values based on time interval if they belong to

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, rows, repeat

I have a Pandas dataframe with many columns. Two of then are timestamp (`start` and `end`).

```
       start                 end             value  string
    2021-12-01 14:00:00     2021-12-01 14:35:00     1   a
    2021-12-01 17:00:00     2021-12-01 17:30:00     2   b
    2021-12-01 14:00:00     2021-12-01 16:00:00     3   c
```

I need to standardize a timestamp marker (column `time` below) from 5 to 5 minutes repeting the values from the other columns `value` and `string` that belongs to the same time interval, like this:

```
 

           time                  start               end             value  string
    2021-12-01 14:00:00     2021-12-01 14:00:00     2021-12-01 14:35:00     1   a
    2021-12-01 14:05:00     2021-12-01 14:00:00     2021-12-01 14:35:00     1   a
    2021-12-01 14:10:00     2021-12-01 14:00:00     2021-12-01 14:35:00     1   a
    2021-12-01 14:15:00     2021-12-01 14:00:00     2021-12-01 14:35:00     1   a
    2021-12-01 14:20:00     2021-12-01 14:00:00     2021-12-01 14:35:00     1   a
    2021-12-01 14:25:00     2021-12-01 14:00:00     2021-12-01 14:35:00     1   a
    2021-12-01 14:30:00     2021-12-01 14:00:00     2021-12-01 14:35:00     1   a
    2021-12-01 17:00:00     2021-12-01 17:00:00     2021-12-01 17:30:00     2   b
    2021-12-01 17:05:00     2021-12-01 17:00:00     2021-12-01 17:30:00     2   b

....
```

There are many intersections on time intervals, so I woldn't be able to use `df.resample` with `DatetimeIndex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a date range with `pd.date_range` for each row, and then `explode` them:

```
new_df = df.assign(time=df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['start'], x['end'], freq='5min'), axis=1)).explode('time').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> new
                 start                 end  value string                time
0  2021-12-01 14:00:00 2021-12-01 14:35:00      1      a 2021-12-01 14:00:00
1  2021-12-01 14:00:00 2021-12-01 14:35:00      1      a 2021-12-01 14:05:00
2  2021-12-01 14:00:00 2021-12-01 14:35:00      1      a 2021-12-01 14:10:00
3  2021-12-01 14:00:00 2021-12-01 14:35:00      1      a 2021-12-01 14:15:00
4  2021-12-01 14:00:00 2021-12-01 14:35:00      1      a 2021-12-01 14:20:00
5  2021-12-01 14:00:00 2021-12-01 14:35:00      1      a 2021-12-01 14:25:00
6  2021-12-01 14:00:00 2021-12-01 14:35:00      1      a 2021-12-01 14:30:00
7  2021-12-01 14:00:00 2021-12-01 14:35:00      1      a 2021-12-01 14:35:00
8  2021-12-01 17:00:00 2021-12-01 17:30:00      2      b 2021-12-01 17:00:00
9  2021-12-01 17:00:00 2021-12-01 17:30:00      2      b 2021-12-01 17:05:00
...
```

Comment: Thanks richardec! But I've got a error "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index". 

I try to use closed='left' inside date_range, but the error persists.

I'm new on Python. Any idea about this error?

Comment: Without more of your data, I can't really tell you what's going on. It should work - I'm not sure why it's not. :(

Comment: Richardec, I was using an old version (0.22.0) of Pandas. I upgrade for Version: 1.1.5 and your solution works perfectly! Thank you!

Successfully installed numpy-1.19.5 pandas-1.1.5 python-dateutil-2.8.2